# Error in JTable java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7 >= 7

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I'm having a trouble with my JTable connected to Database. As soon as i add, delete or modify any data, the table changes correctly. However, after using the the Table's filter searcher, when i try to add something, the table doesn't show it until i make another search. The update button is the only working.

Code to add the database to the JTable and update it when i make a change:

```
public void show_database(){
        try {
               Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
               cn = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/modificar?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL", "root", "");
               pst = (PreparedStatement)cn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM person");
               rs = pst.executeQuery();
               table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
               
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        
    }
```

The filter's code:

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
 TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tr = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(dtm);
 table.setRowSorter(tr);
 int column=0;
        if (combo.getSelectedItem()=="ID"){
            column = 0;
        }
        else if(combo.getSelectedItem()=="Name"){
            column = 1;
        }
        else if(combo.getSelectedItem()=="Surname"){
            column = 2;
        }
        else if(combo.getSelectedItem()=="Adress"){
            column = 3;
        }
        tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(filtertxt.getText(), column));
```

Code to delete:

```
try {
            pst = (PreparedStatement)cn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM person WHERE id=(?)");
            pst.setInt(1, Integer.valueOf(idtxt.getText().toLowerCase()));
            pst.executeUpdate();
            idtxt.setText("");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "DELETED");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        show_database();
```

Moreover, when i try to delete, it gives me this error. Also, the data i deleted is shown once i use the filter again.:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8 >= 8
    at java.base/java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:463)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:660)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2706)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5724)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(BasicTableUI.java:2190)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(BasicTableUI.java:2092)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(BasicTableUI.java:1888)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:797)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1074)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5255)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBufferedImpl(RepaintManager.java:1643)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1618)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1556)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1323)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5203)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5013)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:865)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:848)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:848)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:823)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:772)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1884)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: Deleting data from a database has no effect on the data being displayed in a JTable.  If you have logic that deletes data from a JTable, then should be no need to reset the filter. Don't use "==" for String comparison. Instead use the `equals(...)` method to compare objects. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. So hardcode some data in a tale and then filter the data. The database is irrelevant to filtering of data in the JTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i solve it just adding this to the filter's code:

```
if (filter.getText().equals("")){
           table.setRowSorter(null);
       }
       else{
           tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(filter.getText(), column));
       }
```